# How to rewrite to a specific server according to the subdomain name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, subdomain, iis-8

A domain name is pointing to the web server named "Rewrite" (asp.net mvc application). I would like to query the database and rewrite all the pages from another web server according to subdomain name. Each customer has a specific subdomain. Basically, every page will be generated from another web server.
I just want the "Rewrite" web server to show the pages from another server which will be selected dynamically according to the subdomain name.

For example:

- If **user1.mydomain.com** is requested to the mydomain server that will use the web server **www1**, but the url on the client side won't change: **user1.mydomain.com**
- If **user1.mydomain.com/Report** is requested to the mydomain server that will use the web server **www1** (so **www1/Report**), but the url on the client side won't change: **user1.mydomain.com/Report**
- If **user2.mydomain.com** is requested to the mydomain server that will use the web server **www2**, but the url on the client side won't change: **user2.mydomain.com**

I've read we can add a rewrite rule in the web.config file, but it seems to be a static solution. Unless I can have an automated process to modify the web.config file automatically when we need to create/modify/remove a new client (subdomain) and create a long configuration list. Also, we can have a few thousand clients.

It is a new architecture solution, so the web servers can be hosted on Azure App Service or it can use IIS on a VM.

Also, will that work with a SSL wildcard?

Any idea would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a reverse proxy server. You can do this with IIS but as you mentioned the rules are somewhat static, so for every "user#" to "www#" pair you may have to setup a new rule, unless maybe the number on the www side always matches the number on the user side (I'm guessing that's not the case"

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2010/04/01/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr/

There may be a more efficient way to do this with NGINX (take a look at the LUA and MAP modules as options).